# Pandas : Valid regex doesn't seem to work with str.extract on dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this csv file with data about the presidents of usa. I'm stuck where I have a column (`Age atstart of presidency`) which has both Age at start of presidency and date of start of presidency concatenated. So i came up with a regex that separates them both and i works (tested on regex101) and when tested with a single series object but it doesnt seem to work when I pass it to the whole dataframe.

In short, I have a column named `Age atstart of presidency` which has data like `57 years, 67 daysApr 30, 1789` and my job is to separate the age and date.
i.e -

```
age                       date
57 years, 67 days      Apr 30, 1789
```

But the problem is that the regex doesn't work with the whole dataframe but works when I pass a single series object (I find this very weird since when I specify a column like so `df['cName']` I'm technically doing operating on the underlying `Series` object. Am I right?)

Here is the code -

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("datasets/presidents.csv")
pattern = r"(?P<age>.+ days)(?P<start>.+ \w{4})"

s = pd.Series({'date' : '57 years, 67 daysApr 30, 1789'})

print(s.str.extract(pattern))             #this works 
print('--'*10)
print(df['Age atstart of presidency'].str.extract(pattern).head())   #doesn't work
```

output -

```
                    age         start
date  57 years, 67 days  Apr 30, 1789
----------------------
   age start
0  NaN   NaN
1  NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN
3  NaN   NaN
4  NaN   NaN
```

If anyone needs the dataset I'm working on - https://file.re/2021/06/14/presidents/

Comment: Works for me. If you still have a problem, make sure to create a reproducible example.

Comment: hey, works for you how ? on the dataframe when you import the csv file i linked ? or on the single series object `s`??

Comment: Both works for me - I copied the csv file from the link you provided

Comment: Workd for me too. In the unlikely events of issues, please try 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['57 years, 67 daysApr 30, 1789']})`

`df=df.assign(Age=df['date'].str.split('days').str[0]+'days', startdate=df['date'].str.split('days').str[1])`

Comment: @Psidom how is that possible? I tried it on two machines and always get `nan`.

Comment: @Psidom thanks for the hint you gave, I went to that link and copied the data from the preview window and pasted it in a new csv file and for some reason it works now. what is going on? why it didnt work with the original file ? any idea

Comment: @wwnde thanks, dude I went to that link and copied the data from the preview window and pasted it in a new csv file and for some reason it works now. what is going on? why it didnt work with the original file ? any idea

Comment: Depends on the method you're using to read, should have been okay but again, engines can cause change

Comment: @wwnde wdym by method ? as you can see i used the `pd.read_csv` to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, as @Psidom pointed out, I copied the data from the preview window from the link i posted and pasted it in a new csv file and imported it. Ran the same code on it and it magically worked.
I still do not get the cause of the issue but it is solved.